# cakephp don't display image blanked path

Tags: image, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP 2.0 and i have a problem with image. My images have path as following: webroot/img/sources/picture - copy.jpg and webroot/img/sources/picture2.jpg.

The first image don't display in view (i think its path has blank), but the second displays in view.

How can I display these image ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should avoid using whitespases `-` in image name in future.
Use `str_replace(' ', '_')` on saving images.

But to fix already stored images try to use `urlencode('image name.jpg');`

Comment: It's great. I displayed these images according to your way.

Comment: Great! I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `urlencode();`
like `urlencode('image name with spaces.jpg');`

Comment: Your answer is similar to Dimitrioglo's. It's works.